# How to implement glDrawElementsBaseVertex in OpenGL ES 3.0

Tags: ndk, opengl-es3

I want to convert simple OpenGL project to Android native using OpenGL ES3.0, one of the functions which is not implemented is `glDrawElementsBaseVertex`, I have one VBO which contains many entries inside and known each offset and size, so how can I implement this function by `glDrawElements` method or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Disclaimer I haven't touched OpenGLES on Android and I definitely haven't done any benchmarking) I can think of two options here:

1. just have a really large index array with all the offsets in them. This takes up a lot more space, but it should still be small-ish (4 bytes per vertex maybe) compared to your vertex data.
2. For each mesh, Re-bind your attributes with different offsets. This now requires separate VAOs for each mesh to store the different attributes.

Comment: I think the second solution is more suitable for me, thank you